# mouse down event from android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, leaflet

I have piece of javascript code that works with mouse event in leaflet map to drag a circle, works in web pages not in android webview, my code looks like this:

```
var isDragCircle = true;
map.on('mouseup', function (){
    isDragCircle = false;
    //showAndroidLog('mouse up event');
});

circle.on('mousedown', function (event) {
    isDragCircle = true;
    //showAndroidLog('mouse down event');
    //L.DomEvent.stop(event);
    map.dragging.disable();
    let {lat: circleStartingLat, lng: circleStartingLng} = circle._latlng;
    let {lat: mouseStartingLat, lng: mouseStartingLng} = event.latlng;

    map.on('mousemove', event => {
        if (isDragCircle) {
            let {lat: mouseNewLat, lng: mouseNewLng} = event.latlng;
            let latDifference = mouseStartingLat - mouseNewLat;
            let lngDifference = mouseStartingLng - mouseNewLng;

            let center = [circleStartingLat-latDifference, circleStartingLng-lngDifference];
            circle.setLatLng(center);
        };

    });
});
```

try out this in index.html inside my assets folder but mousedown event not triggered in webview, my goal is to drag leaflet circle from android webview.

note: havent try with mouse with usb otg, but how to implement this with touch event i guess.

edit:
still trying but no result to drag a circle, temporary use click event to change circle coordinate, like this:

```
map.on('click', function (e){
    if (circleDrawn) {
        circle.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    };
});
```

edit:just read from leaflet docs [support tap](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-tap) (fired as contextmenu events).